# Is there a SUMMAX or a "No Greater Than" like function in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have some data that needs to be summed but I would like to set the maximum value at 20, so sum the values but the greatest number that would be returned is 20.

For example, let's say I have three columns labeled A, B, and C. If in row one, the values are 5, 5, 5, the sum should be 15. But if they are 10, 10, 10, I would like the "sum" to show 20 instead of 30.

I have been playing around the the GT() function, but I would not like to create a new column just for comparisons. I would like it all to be in one cell. What would be a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   =MIN(20, SUM(A1:C1))
```

maybe? That's what I'd use in Excel...